# How to Assign Session variables using Javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, session

I want to Assign session variable using java script. I find this code that works fine

```
function SetUserName()
{
    var userName = "Shekhar Shete";
    <%Session["UserName"] = "' + userName + '"; %>;
     alert('<%=Session["UserName"] %>');
}
```

The problem that i use vb.net as language and not c#. I want have the same code with vb.net.
Does anybody have any suggestion to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Session["UserName"] equivalent is Session("UserName") in vb.net

Comment: Javascript is client side, sessions are server side. You can only get/set a session on a postback. An option would be to send to username through an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

For VB.Net you can rewrite the same as

```
<%Session("UserName") = "' + userName + '"%>
alert('<%=Session("UserName") %>');
```

Also if you want to convert your piece of code from c# to VB , you can take help from : http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb

Comment: i want using the variable userName and not the string userName

Comment: I want have in the session the content of variable userName

Comment: @Dhibi_Mohanned I formatted your code to VB.Net ... And if that's the case my friend then what you have posted will take the vb/c# variable not the js one

Answer (score 0):

```
<%Session(userName) = "' + userName + '"%>
alert('<%=Session(userName) %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is using ajax  on jquery:

serverside: (c#   file.aspx.cs)

```
public static string SesionValue
    {
        set { System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["session_value"] = value; }
        get
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["session_value"] != null)
            {
                return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["session_value"] as string;
            }
            return string.Empty;
 
        }
    }
```

and create a webmethod that asign the value:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static object SesionValue(string texto)
    {
        object result = new object();
        SesionValue = texto; 
        
        result = new
            {
                status="OK"
            };
        return result;
    }
```

on Clientside ( file.aspx):

```
$('#<%= txtprueba.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                    debugger;
                    var text = $('#<%= txtprueba.ClientID %>').val();                    
                    
                    if (gender.length > 0) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "file.aspx/SesionValue",
                            data: "{ texto: '" + text+ "'}",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (result) {
                                debugger;
                                console.log("ok, Sesion guardada");                               
                            },
                            error: function (msg) {
                                MessageBox('Ocurrio un Error: ' + msg, null, 'alert', null);
                            }
                        });//ajax
                    }


                });
```